# How to find css sources via NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I see the js files that can be installed using npm, for example:

```
npm install angular-loading-bar
```

But the css file should be placed in index.html using a CDN. I don't want that. I want to import/require the css file as well, but where it can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `npm install` to install an npm package, its files are copied to the directory `node_modules`.

Search for the CSS file here, you’ll find it in `node_modules/angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.css`.

This means you can import or require the CSS file like this:

```
import 'angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.css';
require('angular-loading-bar/src/loading-bar.css');
```